# download Line pictures but get permission denied

Tags: java, url, networking, connect

I'm trying to use Java to download these comic pictures. I had get those pictures' Url from HTML code, but when i connect to it, server tells me that i don't have the permission to access the pictures on it.
I try to find out if there's some post or get request to ask for the permission, but cannot find it. Can someone help me about the idea of getting the access?
Thanks a lot ^ ^ !

Link of the page : http://www.webtoons.com/zh-hant/drama/yushentongxing/%E7%AC%AC1%E8%A9%B1-%E7%A5%9E%E7%9A%84%E5%AF%A9%E5%88%A4-01/viewer?title_no=734&episode_no=1

and link of the picture : http://webtoon.phinf.naver.net/20160901_41/1472713930299oYcIe_JPEG/147271393026973416.jpg?type=q90

Denied message:

Referral Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://webtoon.phinf.naver.net/20160901_41/1472713930299oYcIe_JPEG/147271393026973416.jpg?" on this server.
Reference #24.5e41ca3.1516454916.3d5b39b

Here's my code for download pictures:

```
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(output));
```

Comment: could you post your code, so that we can get what exactly is wrong

Comment: I considered maybe the wrong was on the connection request(?), because even load the picture by browser will get access denied too.

Comment: Add a sample code to your question.

Comment: I can access this url from browser http://webtoon.phinf.naver.net/20160901_41/1472713930299oYcIe_JPEG/147271393026973416.jpg?type=q90.....adding ?type=q90 did good for the 2nd url also

Comment: @Fred  i have put it on

Comment: @100rabh press F5 and cannot get it anymore :((

Comment: That is something that server denies, nothing much we can do I guess....Alternatively you could use selenium..that will do the work

Comment: because we can access the pictures trough the webpage which i put in the first link, so i guest is there something just did when we connect to the page(?) like some request.
anyway i'll try selenium :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server simply checks **Referer** HTTP Header to be matched to "http://www.webtoons.com/" (automatically added by browser when loading the image from the page)

So adding this header via API should be sufficient, following code prints 200 success code for me:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://webtoon.phinf.naver.net/20160901_41/1472713930299oYcIe_JPEG/147271393026973416.jpg?type=q90");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.webtoons.com/");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(responseCode);
```

Comment: wow, i see :)
it really works!
i had set the header to the entire webpage url and got failed LOL
and finally successfully complete my "crawler" ^ ^